# Проблема с отступом (Bootstrap)

Tags: html, css, bootstrap, инспекция-кода

Здравствуйте!
У меня при вёрстке появился какой-то отступ, прикрепляю разметку, заранее благодарен за помощь!

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Благотворительная общественная организация "Люди-Бабочки"</title>
  <link rel="shortcut icon" href="favicon.ico" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap-theme.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/font-awesome.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/styles.css" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <script src="js/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
  <script src="js/min/modernizr-custom-v2.7.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script src="js/min/jquery-finger-v0.1.0.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

    <!--Include flickerplate-->
    <link href="css/flickerplate.css"  type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="js/min/flickerplate.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

    <!--Execute flickerplate-->
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){

        $('.flicker-example').flicker();
    });
    </script>

</head>

<body>

  <div class="header">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">

        <div class="col-md-1 col-xs-4">

          <img src="img/logo.png" alt="" class="logo">

        </div>

        <div class="col-md-3 col-xs-8">

          <p class="logotext">Благотворительная общественная
                              организация “Люди-бабочки”</p>
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-4 col-xs-8">

          <input type="text" class="search" size="36" placeholder="Поиск">
          <input type="image" src="img/search.png" alt="Найти" class="find">
          <div class="separators"></div>

        </div> 

        <div class="col-md-4 col-xs-12">

          <h1 class="phone">+7 924 920-52-06</h1>

            <br>
            <a href=""><i class="fa top fa-vk" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
            <a href=""><i class="fa top fa-facebook" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
            <a href=""><i class="fa top fa-twitter" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
            <a href=""><i class="fa top fa-odnoklassniki" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
            <a href=""><i class="fa top fa-youtube-play" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
            <a href=""><i class="fa top fa-google-plus" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
            <a href=""><i class="fa top fa-instagram" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>

        </div>

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

<div class="container">

  <div class="row">

    <ul class="menu">
      <li>об организации</li>
      <li>наши бабочки</li>
      <li>новости</li>
      <li>мероприятия</li>
      <li>пациентам</li>
      <li>врачам</li>
      <li>помощь</li>
      <li>юридическая поддержка</li>
      <li>членство</li>
    </ul>

    <br><br><br>
<div id="controls">
<div id="yandex_ad"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
(function(w, d, n, s, t) {
    w[n] = w[n] || [];
    w[n].push(function() {
        Ya.Direct.insertInto(84098, "yandex_ad", {
            ad_format: "direct",
            type: "240x400",
            border_type: "block",
            border_radius: true,
            site_bg_color: "FFFFFF",
            header_bg_color: "FEEAC7",
            bg_color: "FFF9F0",
            border_color: "FBE5C0",
            title_color: "0000CC",
            url_color: "006600",
            text_color: "000000",
            hover_color: "0066FF",
            favicon: true,
            no_sitelinks: false
        });
    });
    t = d.getElementsByTagName("script")[0];
    s = d.createElement("script");
    s.src = "//an.yandex.ru/system/context.js";
    s.type = "text/javascript";
    s.async = true;
    t.parentNode.insertBefore(s, t);
})(window, document, "yandex_context_callbacks");
</script>
</div>

    <!--Basic example-->
    <div class="flicker-example" data-block-text="false">

        <ul>

            <li data-background="img/slider1.png">
                <div class="flick-title">ПОМОЖЕМ ВМЕСТЕ!</div>
            </li>

            <li data-background="img/slider1.png">
                <div class="flick-title">ПОМОЖЕМ ВМЕСТЕ!</div>
            </li>

            <li data-background="img/slider1.png">
                <div class="flick-title">ПОМОЖЕМ ВМЕСТЕ!</div>
            </li>

            <li data-background="img/slider1.png">
                <div class="flick-title">ПОМОЖЕМ ВМЕСТЕ!</div>
            </li>

            <li data-background="img/slider1.png">
                <div class="flick-title">ПОМОЖЕМ ВМЕСТЕ!</div>
            </li>

            <li data-background="img/slider1.png">
                <div class="flick-title">ПОМОЖЕМ ВМЕСТЕ!</div>
            </li>

            <li data-background="img/slider1.png">
                <div class="flick-title">ПОМОЖЕМ ВМЕСТЕ!</div>
            </li>

            <li data-background="img/slider1.png">
                <div class="flick-title">ПОМОЖЕМ ВМЕСТЕ!</div>
            </li>

            <li data-background="img/slider1.png">
                <div class="flick-title">ПОМОЖЕМ ВМЕСТЕ!</div>
            </li>

            <li data-background="img/slider1.png">
                <div class="flick-title">ПОМОЖЕМ ВМЕСТЕ!</div>
            </li>

        </ul>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-3 col-xs-6 col-md-offset-1">
        <h2 class="nashi">НАШИ-БАБОЧКИ</h2>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-2 col-xs-6 col-md-offset-1">
        <a href="" class="orangebtn"><div class="orangebtn">Все программы</div></a>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-5 col-xs-12">
        <div class="total">ВСЕГО СОБРАНО ЗА 2017 ГОД<br>
                        1 000 000,00 РУБЛЕЙ</div>
    </div>

  </div>

</div>

    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">


    <div class="col-md-7 col-xs-12">

        <div class="col-md-4 col-xs-12">
            <a href="" class="links">Тарехова Катя</a>
            <img src="img/linkspng.png" class="linksimg" alt="">
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4 col-xs-12">
            <a href="" class="links">Тарехова Катя</a>
            <img src="img/linkspng.png" class="linksimg" alt="">
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4 col-xs-12">
            <a href="" class="links">Тарехова Катя</a>
            <img src="img/linkspng.png" class="linksimg" alt="">
        </div>

    </div>

        </div>
    </div>


</body>

</html>
```

CSS:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: "Helvetic";
  src: url("../fonts/Helveticafont.otf") format("opentype");
}

@font-face {
  font-family: "Helveticaroman";
  src: url("../fonts/Helveticaroman.otf") format("opentype");
}

html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background: #d0ecfd;
}

 :active,
 :hover,
 :focus {
  outline: 0;
  outline-offset: 0;
}

div.header {
  background-color: #0070b9;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
}

img.logo {
  position: relative;
  margin-top: 20px;
}

p.logotext {
  color: #ffffff;
  font-size: 1em;
  font-family: "Helvetic", sans-serif;
  letter-spacing: 0.5px;
  position: relative;
  margin-top: 27.5px;
}

input.search {
  position: relative;
  padding: 3px 0px 3px 5px;
  margin-top: 32px;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-family: "Helvetic", sans-serif;
  border: 1px solid #e6e9eb;
}

.find {
  position: relative;
  background: #e6e9eb !important;
  padding: 7px 8px 6px 8px;
  top: 9px;
  right: 2%;
  display: inline-block;
}

div.separators {
  background-color: #e6e9eb;
  width: 1px;
  height: 52px;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  top: 30px;
  left: 66px;
}

h1.phone {
  font-family: "Open Sans Bold", sans-serif;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 2em;
  display: inline-block;
  color: #ffffff;
  letter-spacing: 3px;
  position: relative;
  margin-top: 12px;
  left: 55px;
}

.top {
  color: #ffffff;
  background-color: #99c6e3;
  padding: 10px 10px;
  display: inline-block;
  border-radius: 3px;
  margin-left: 5px;
  position: relative;
  left: 35px;
}

ul.menu>li {
  list-style-type: none;
  display: inline-block;
  color: #fff;
  margin-left: 35px;
  font-family: "Helveticaroman", sans-serif;
}

ul.menu {
  background-color: #bdbdbd;
  padding: 8px 15px;

}

h2.nashi {
  position: relative;
  margin-top: 0%;
  top: 25px;
}

div.orangebtn {
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #eea72b;
  width: 202px;
  position: relative;
  height: 35px;
  color: #fff;
  padding-top: 5px;
  font-size: 1.4em;
  right: 40px;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  font-family: "Helvetic", sans-serif;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 3px 3px 8px 0px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.67);
  -moz-box-shadow:    3px 3px 8px 0px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.67);
  box-shadow:         3px 3px 8px 0px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.67);
  transition: 0.25s;
  top: 25px;
}

div.orangebtn:hover {
  background-color: #e29c23;
  transition: 0.25s ease-in-out;
}

a.orangebtn {
  text-decoration: none !important;
}

div.total {
  background-color: #d1ecfd;
  width: 472px;
  height: 103px;
  font-family: "Open Sans Bold", sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 1.700em;
  color: #565656;
  font-weight: bold;
  position: relative;
  padding-top: 17.5px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 3px 3px 8px 0px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.67);
  -moz-box-shadow:    3px 3px 8px 0px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.67);
  box-shadow:         3px 3px 8px 0px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.67);
}

a.links {
  color: #094f83;
  position: relative;
  text-decoration: underline;
  font-size: 1em;
  font-family: "Open Sans Bold", sans-serif;
  font-weight: bold;
  letter-spacing: 0.5px;

}

img.linksimg {
  width: 209px;
  height: 153px;
  position: relative;

}
```

Comment: Простое решение - попробуй переопределить. Добавь в свой css файлик `.container {padding-left: 0px;}`.

Comment: @learp проблему не решило.

Comment: Через @important тоже.

Comment: Мне нужно разместить эти блоки на один уровень с логотипом http://imgur.com/a/3cC3B

Comment: А вот с .row прокатило

Comment: Но разве это является правильным решением?

Comment: нет, в целом это не очень хорошее решение. Оно зависит от последовательности подключения файликов css и т.д. Другой вариант - поменять прям в bootstrap. Это получше, но все равно плохо. Как сделать идеально сходу не знаю. Поэтому и не оформлял в качестве ответа :)

Comment: @learp Кажется догнал в чём дело, у меня 2 контейнера и 2 row, оставил один и исправилось